# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py_geo_nearby'

Tags: python, geolocation, geospatial

I've installed the required package based on the documentation, However, I wasn't able to import py_geo_nearby.py_geo_nearby
Failing with error message ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py_geo_nearby'

```
pip install geopy
pip install py-geo-nearby
pip install py_geo_nearby

import py_geo_nearby.py_geo_nearby as pygn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py_geo_nearby'
```

https://pypi.org/project/py-geo-nearby/

Comment: Its possible that your `python` and `pip` are from two different distributions. On mac/linux you can type `which python` and `which pip` to see. You can also run pip under your python `python -m pip ..`

Comment: I removed old installation and reinstalled package with python -m pip .., but it is still not working, same error message is returned

Comment: I think the wheel is broken. Perhaps you can contact the maintainers via the pypi page https://pypi.org/project/py-geo-nearby/